# OnComplete is called after activity destruction in FirebaseStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm downloading an image using Firebase Storage in this way:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
storageReference.child("images/").child("myimage.jpg").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnCompleteListener(this);
```

And I added a listener to know when the download finishes:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<byte[]> task)
{
    //stuff...
}
```

The problem occurs when I remove Internet, try to download the image and destroy the activity. The call should be destroyed because the activity is destroyed, however it remains stored. In fact when I activate Internet, the method onComplete is called despite the activity is destroyed. This last **isn't** created again, I checked all with logs. So how can I interrupt definitely the call? And why is the method called?

Comment: Your method is called because you retain a strong memory reference to `Activity` object in another thread, which treats it like "completion listener". It actually pretty bad for memory as well, because activity won't be garbage collected. You should remove activity from listeners when it's destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

The task API has your back: use the `addOn[...]Listener(Activity, On[...]Listener)` variants. Then the listener will be automatically removed in the activity's `onStop()` method. For your case, it would look like this:

```
...addOnCompleteListener(this, this);
```

Here's the [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E))

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [StorageReference.html#getFile](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getFile(java.io.File)) method so you can get a cancellable [FileDownloadTask](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask).

Lets say you call make your calls in `onCreate()` and want to cancel in the `onDestroy()` method,

```
/**
 * reference to the download file task
 */
FileDownloadTask downloadTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get the StorageReference to the images folder
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/");
    // create the download file task
    downloadTask = storageReference.getFile(new File("myimage.jpg"));
    // this activity should also implement OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>
    downloadTask.addOnCompleteListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (downloadTask != null) {
        downloadTask.cancel();
        downloadTask = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

More info in the docs here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot

hope this helps.